# The mean of the square root of a function of a Gaussian distributed random variable

Tags: normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Firstly, excuse my lack of jargon as I am a physicist and have a limited statistical scope. Suppose I have a finite data set of N points which are normally distributed with a mean, $\langle x \rangle$, of zero and a standard deviation, $\sqrt{\langle x^2 \rangle}$, of $\sigma_x$.

Now, suppose I wanted to create a new data set with the following expression:

$$z_{ij}= a-b\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+c(1+(x_i-x_j))},$$

where $a,b,$ and $c$ are constants, and the $(x_i, x_j)$ values are from our normally distributed data set. The expression for $z_{ij}$ would generated for all $(x_i, x_j)$ pairs and result in a data set of $N^2$ points (all $z_{ii}$ elements would be equal).

Is there a closed expression for the standard deviation of $z_{ij}$? My attempt so far:

$$
\begin{align}
(z_{ij})^2 &= \left( a-b\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+c(1+(x_i-x_j))}\right)^2 \\
           &= a^2 + b^2\left( {(x_i-x_j)^2+c(1+(x_i-x_j))} \right) - 2ab\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+c(1+(x_i-x_j))}
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\langle(z_{ij})^2\rangle &= \langle a^2\rangle + b^2\langle\left( {(x_i-x_j)^2+c(1+(x_i-x_j))} \right)\rangle - 2ab\langle\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+c(1+(x_i-x_j))}\rangle  \\
   &=  a^2 +b^2\left({2\sigma_x^2+c}\right) - 2ab\langle\sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2+c(1+(x_i-x_j))}\rangle
\end{align}
$$

This is where I get stuck because of the mean of the square root is something I do not know how to handle. Any ideas?

Comment: Is $z_{ij}$ defined? For example if $x_i=0$, $x_j=2$ and $c=5$ you are taking the square root of a negative number!

Comment: @winperikle Good point! I missed that but $z_{ij}$ is always positive. The constant c   is small such that the argument of the square root is always positive.

Comment: Should work for $0 \le c \le 4$. But your $z_{ij}$'s are dependent, you must take that into account.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen What do you mean by taking $z_{ij}$ dependency into account? I think evaluating the mean of the rooted expression should solve my problem entirely.